# Cron Unix dude with shell

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I need make a task with cron but it doesn't work.

My code cron

`*/1 * * * * /home/script.sh`

does not call the script.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How did you schedule it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your path to the script. Maybe it is located in user directory.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

Comment: I have used  pwd  and I wrote this address